# Magento multiple form submission

Tags: forms, magento, submit

On magento's default forms like frontend login form, when I click the login button multiple times, it also submits multiple times

Comment: That sounds like the normal behaviour for any web app

Comment: do you have any walkarounds? or solutions?

Comment: I guess you could disable the form (or the button) once it has been submitted using JavaScript.

Comment: okay I have done that but the form doesn't submit this is the way I disable it

Comment: $j(document).ready(function(){
 $j('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
  lockoutSubmit(this);
 });

 
});


function lockoutSubmit(button) {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 1000)
}

Comment: Try adding `return true;` after you call `lockoutSubmit`

Comment: Ahh use `.submit` instead of `.click`

Comment: hmm.. the form submits but the form is submitted multiple times

Comment: which browser your getting this error.